# How to convert typescript from stateless to stateful

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to convert my code from stateless to stateful component in Typescript. I am a newbie, so it quite difficult to me. My code as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }: any) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
);

export default AppRoute;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a class component? Not really sure what you mean by "convert" here, or why its relevant to typescript. also if you're using react 16.8 and higher, you can just add the `useState` hook

Comment: there's a section in the docs answering your question https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class

Answer (score 0):

It's not really different from non-Typescript stateful component syntax.

Take a look on an example from [here (this link can be useful for you as a ts-react beginner)](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; // let's also import Component

// the clock's state has one field: The current time, based upon the
// JavaScript class Date
type ClockState = {
  time: Date
}

// Clock has no properties, but the current state is of type ClockState
// The generic parameters in the Component typing allow to pass props
// and state. Since we don't have props, we pass an empty object.
export class Clock extends Component<{}, ClockState> {

  // The tick function sets the current state. TypeScript will let us know
  // which ones we are allowed to set.
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      time: new Date()
    });
  }

  // Before the component mounts, we initialise our state
  componentWillMount() {
    this.tick();
  }

  // After the component did mount, we set the state each second.
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  // render will know everything!
  render() {
    return <p>The current time is {this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
  }
}
```